# Random spacing between RecyclerView GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a small app to display all images in the users DCIM folder, by now all works fine, except one small issue. As seen in the images below, the RecyclerView adds spacing between the rows. After googleing for about 1 hour and not finding anything I hope one of you guys can help.

Here is the code of the ViewAdapter:

```
class BackgroundsViewAdapter(
    var images: List<File>,
    private val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BackgroundsViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BackgroundsViewHolder {
        val view = ImageView(parent.context)
        view.bottom = 0
        view.top = 0
        return BackgroundsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BackgroundsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso
            .get()
            .load(images[position])
            .centerCrop()
            .resize(300, 300)
            .into(holder.imageView)
    }
}
```

The RecyclerView is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/backgrounds_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

viewManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 4)
viewAdapter = BackgroundsViewAdapter(ArrayList(), this)

recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.backgrounds_view).apply {
    setHasFixedSize(true)
    layoutManager = viewManager
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post your item view layout code please

Comment: @Sdghasemi It is posted in the first code snippet. I initialize it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not hard codding width & height to 300. Calculate the device size and divide it by the grid size, in this case, 4.
Set that width and height to the IamgeView as well.

Comment: It actually worked. Do you know why it didn't work with the hard coded values?

Comment: Well with wrong sizes the image is cropped more than it should look like a square. When you are working with view layouts I suggest to enable Layout Boundaries on your phone Dev settings, to have a better understanding on how much space each view is occupying.